# jfrog artifactory - show xml with all directories data

Tags: xml, artifactory

I am trying to save as xml file data about directories and files
After I am logged-in I am using `http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/storage/MyDir/Inter`
 To display the "MyDir" content
1. How can I display that data without login to Artifactory, how and where can i "plant the username and password parameters?
2. Is there any other option to get XML file that contains all the data bellow?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query that you are using is a file list query, which is identical to the [Artifactory REST API (Filelist)](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileList).

Regarding the permissions if you will use the REST API then you can insert your credentials while committing the command, for example:

```
curl -i -u{UserName}:{Password} http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/storage/MyDir/Inter
```

This is a JSON file and not XML.

In case that you wish to list all of the files under this folder, you can add parameters such as list, deep, listFolders.

Comment: Hi Ariel

Thank you!
I am really new in this so i`ve got som eclarification questions 

1. Which tool allows me to use REST API ?
2. Is there any other way to store this json file ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, You can use a tool named 'curl' for issuing REST API commands (HTTP requests). There are also several browsers add-ons that will allow you to do so as well. 

Regarding the other format, this specific rest will only return JSON.